# xsltprocessor debugging in Chrome

Tags: javascript, xslt, google-chrome

This code::

```
xslProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
xslProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
result =  xslProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
```

works fine in Firefox, but result is null in Google Chrome. xsl and xml are both loaded from the network via XMLHTTPRequest, and show as Documents in the Chrome JS console. How can I get more information from Chrome about why the transform is failing? (There are no errors reported in the Chrome Javascript debugging window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Chrome doesn't support `<xsl:import>`

Comment: Were you able to find a way of supporting Chrome? I've got an eye to do something similar.

Comment: Not exactly - I do the import on the server side. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620589/xslimport-using-stylesheets for more details.