# xsl:import and xsl:include in stylesheets don't work on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, xslt

I'm building a website that uses xsl stylesheets, and I'm building up a small library of useful functions in a util stylesheet that other sheets import with

```
<xsl:import href="util" />
```

at the top of every sheet. This doesn't work in Google Chrome, as it doesn't support xsl:import yet. Can someone please write me a stylesheet that I can run on the server side that will read the xsl:import line and import the relevant stylesheet before its sent to the client?

Comment: I don't want to parse the xml on the server side, I want an xsl document that can be applied to other xsl documents. From the documentation I've read, I'd be execting something that uses the "document()" function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do something like the following, which will combine the stylesheet serverside, before it gets to Chrome. The first step is in place because `xsl:import` is not the same as replacing all places with the imported stylesheets.

1. Replace all `xsl:import` with `xsl:include` (import priority isn't applicable to `xsl:include`, so you may need to change your code and use priorities instead)
2. Use the server-side stylesheet below to merge them into one before serving
3. Wait a few weeks (can be months). I've created a fix for Chrome and am currently working with the developers team to include the fix into the build.

```
<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xsl:include">
   <!-- you'll probably want to be a bit more restrictive here -->
   <xsl:copy-of select="document(@href)/xsl:stylesheet/*" />
</xsl:template>
```

**Update:** Just a note: the Chrome bug appears in Safari too.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Nice to hear about the long term fix too!

Comment: You're welcome :) I'll report the SO bug to StackOverflow (if I remove that cursive text, the whole block of code disappears... odd).

Comment: Is there any news about the fix for Chrome?

Comment: @Mikl: I'm not sure. I remember an email exchange with one of the developers on this who asked about some particulars, but it is too long ago to remember it properly. If the fix wasn't implemented in the final release cycles, than that's a waste of the effort, but well, you can't win them all ;). Note that same-origin policy may apply, which means that if you use absolute urls, it may not work, but relative urls may.

Comment: @Abel: I found this bugs related to this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8441 https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60276
Someday we will win =)

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in Python with the libxml2 and libxslt modules... not to do all your work for you, but starting with something like this:

```
import libxml2, libxslt

styledoc = libxml2.parseFile("page.xsl")
style = libxslt.parseStylesheetDoc(styledoc)
doc = libxml2.parseFile("somefile.xml")
result = style.applyStylesheet(doc, None)
```

Then just serve the thing back out.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in php:

```
<?php
$sXml  = "<xml>";
$sXml .= "<testtag>hello tester</testtag>";
$sXml .= "</xml>";

# LOAD XML FILE
$XML = new DOMDocument();
$XML->loadXML( $sXml );

# START XSLT
$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$XSL = new DOMDocument();
$XSL->load( 'xsl/index.xsl', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$xslt->importStylesheet( $XSL );
#PRINT
print $xslt->transformToXML( $XML );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#literal-result-element shows how to solve the duplicate-xsl-namespace issue when writing an XSL stylesheet which transforms your existing XSL stylesheet into an XSL stylesheet with the `<xsl:import>`s expanded.

Be careful, though, about the difference between `<xsl:import>` and `<xsl:include>`.